# Retrieve information from other Org using REST Callout

Tags: visualforce, json, callout, future, schedulebatch

I am new in salesforce and i have a REST request callout to retrieve the information from the other ORG. My problem is, I don't know if my code is correct since there is no error but in my VFPage, there's nothing displayed. Here is my code:

```
public with sharing class ClientController{
public String Response { get; set;}
public List<ConsoleWrapClientInfo> Responses{get;set;}
/*End point Url to web service callout*/
    private final static String ENP_POINT_URL = 'https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token';
    //For development and production https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token
    //And for sandbox https://test.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token
    private final static String REQUEST_BODY = 'grant_type=password&client_id=clientId&client_secret=secret&username=username&password=Password';
    private final static String USERNAME = 'UserName';
    private final static String PASSWORD = 'Password';
    private final static String CONSUMER_KEY = '';
    private final static String CONSUMER_SECRET = '';
//The username, password, consumerkey and secret are given but I deleted it for security purposes
/*public ClientController()
{
Response=fetchData('GET');
}*/
     public class deserializeResponse
    {
        public String client_id;
        public String access_token;
    }
private static OAuth getAccessToken(){
        try{
            HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
            req.setEndpoint(ENP_POINT_URL);
            req.setMethod('POST');          
            Blob headerValue = Blob.valueOf(USERNAME + ':' + PASSWORD);
            String authorizationHeader = 'BASIC ' +
            EncodingUtil.base64Encode(headerValue);
            req.setHeader('Authorization', authorizationHeader); 
            req.setBody(String.format(REQUEST_BODY ,new string[]{CONSUMER_KEY,CONSUMER_SECRET,
                                                                 USERNAME,PASSWORD}));
            req.setTimeout(60000);
            Http http = new Http();
            HttpResponse res = http.send(req);
            OAuth objAuthenticationInfo = (OAuth)JSON.deserialize(res.getbody(), OAuth.class);
            return objAuthenticationInfo;
        }catch(CallOutException ce){
            throw ce;
        }

    }

    /*To get Access token property*/
    public static OAuth authenticationDetail{
        get{
            if(authenticationDetail == null){
                authenticationDetail = getAccessToken();
            }
            return authenticationDetail;
        }set;
    }

    /*To get aouthentication detail Wrapper*/
    public class OAuth{
        public String id{get;set;}
        public String issued_at{get;set;}
        public String instance_url{get;set;}
        public String signature{get;set;}
        public String access_token{get;set;}    
    }   

public List<ConsoleWrapClientInfo> Responses()
{
     if(authenticationDetail == null){
                authenticationDetail = getAccessToken();
            Http h=new Http();
            HttpRequest req=new HttpRequest();
            req.setEndpoint('https://ap4.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/api/PackageLicense');
            req.setHeader('Authorization','Bearer '+''+authenticationDetail);
            req.setMethod('GET');
            HTTPResponse httpResponse = h.send(req);
            //this.result = httpResponse.getBody(); 
            system.debug('httpResponse.getBody() ->'+httpResponse.getBody());
            //queryReturnResponseWrapper QRRW = new queryReturnResponseWrapper();
            //QRRW = (queryReturnResponseWrapper)System.Json.deserialize(response, queryReturnResponseWrapper.class);
        //   Responses = new List<ConsoleWrapClientInfo>();
    if(httpResponse.getstatusCode() == 200 && httpResponse.getbody() != null){
    //system.debug(json.deserializeUntyped(httpResponse.getBody()));
List<ConsoleWrapClientInfo> Responses=(List<ConsoleWrapClientInfo>)json.deserialize(httpResponse.getbody(),List<ConsoleWrapClientInfo>.class);

//ConsoleWrapperList=(List<consolewrap>)json.deserialize(res.getbody(),List<consolewrap>.class);
}
     }
return Responses;
}

    @future(callout=true)
    public static void getQueryResult(){

        if(authenticationDetail != null){
            Http h=new Http();
            HttpRequest req=new HttpRequest();
            req.setEndpoint('https://ap4.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/api/PackageLicense');
            req.setHeader('Authorization','OAuth '+UserInfo.getSessionID());
            req.setMethod('POST');
            HTTPResponse httpResponse = h.send(req);
            //this.result = httpResponse.getBody(); 
            system.debug('httpResponse.getBody() ->'+httpResponse.getBody());
            //queryReturnResponseWrapper QRRW = new queryReturnResponseWrapper();
            //QRRW = (queryReturnResponseWrapper)System.Json.deserialize(response, queryReturnResponseWrapper.class);
            deserializeResponse resp2 = (deserializeResponse)JSON.deserialize(httpResponse.getbody(),deserializeResponse.class);
            Client_Org_Information__c a = [SELECT client_id__c, username__c FROM Client_Org_Information__c WHERE username__c = :USERNAME];
            //a.username__c = resp2.username__c;
            upsert a;
        }

    }

}
```

My VFPage:

```
<apex:page controller="ClientController" title="JSON Table" >

<apex:form >

    <apex:pageBlock ><h1><center>Client Org Packages</center></h1>

<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Responses}" var="wrap">

<apex:column headerValue="Id" value="{!wrap.Id}"/>

<apex:column headerValue="NameSpace Prefix" value="{!wrap.NamespacePrefix}"/>

<apex:column headerValue="Status" value="{!wrap.Status}"/>

<apex:column headerValue="Created Date" value="{!wrap.CreatedDate}"/>

<apex:column headerValue="Last Modified Date" value="{!wrap.LastModifiedDate}"/> 

<apex:column headerValue="Name" value="{!wrap.Name}"/> 

<apex:column headerValue="Version" value="{!wrap.Version}"/> 

</apex:pageBlockTable>

</apex:pageBlock>

</apex:form>

</apex:page>
```

This is my batch class:

```
global class MonitoringBatch implements Database.Batchable<sObject>,Database.AllowsCallouts{
    global final List<Id> Infos = new List<Id>();

    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC)
    {
        return DataBase.getQueryLocator([SELECT client_id__c FROM Client_Org_Information__c WHERE Id IN: Infos]);
        //return MainAcounts;
    }
    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC,List<sObject> scope)
    {        for (Integer i=0;i<scope.size();i++){
            //scopeAcc.get(i).Commercial_Area__c=ownerMap.get(scopeAcc.get(i).OwnerId).Commercial_Area__c;
            ClientController.getQueryResult();
        }
    }
    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC)
    {
}
}
```

And my scheduled Batch to send request everynight at 10pm:

```
global with sharing class CallOutRequestBatchJobSchedule implements Schedulable 
{    
    public static String sched = '0 0 22 * * ?';  //Every 10:00pm 

    global static String CallOutRequestBatchJobSchedule() {
        CallOutRequestBatchJobSchedule SC = new CallOutRequestBatchJobSchedule(); 
        return System.schedule('My batch Job', sched, SC);
    }

    global void execute(SchedulableContext sc){

      MonitoringBatch bns = new MonitoringBatch();
          Database.executeBatch(bns,100);
 }
}
```

Hoping anyone can help me... Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

From what I see, when the page is opened nothing gets executed because it's commented out:

```
/*
public ClientController()
{
    Response=fetchData('GET');
}
*/
```

I don't see any action parameters on your page either. So how do you expect to see something if your code does not invoke it.

Also, you have two getters for `Responses`

```
public List<ConsoleWrapClientInfo> Responses{get;set;}

public List<ConsoleWrapClientInfo> Responses()
{
     if(authenticationDetail == null)
      {
      ....
      }
}
```

Which one gets called is a question. You need to have one getter per property.

You don't need to check for `authenticationDetail == null` in `public List<ConsoleWrapClientInfo> Responses()` because it's already checked and initialized if null here:

```
public static OAuth authenticationDetail{
    get{
        if(authenticationDetail == null){
            authenticationDetail = getAccessToken();
        }
        return authenticationDetail;
    }set;
}
```

When any of your code inside the controller uses the `authenticationDetail` property, it's getter called automatically. It means that:

```
req.setHeader('Authorization','Bearer '+''+authenticationDetail);
```

is identical to:

```
req.setHeader('Authorization','Bearer '+''+ getAuthenticationDetail());
```

Consider adding a `<apex:pageMessages id="msg"/>` tad onto your page and `ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, ce.getMessage()));` instead of rethrowing exceptions `throw ce;`. If you don't catch them on the higher level, which you don't, you'll see an ugly run-time error message on your page. But if you utilize `apex:pageMessages` with `ApexPages.addMessage` your page will show a nicely formatted error, which is much better from user experience perspective at least.

Overall, you've got a bunch of spaghetti code and violation of coding best practices which would be better to refactor to something readable.

Comment: Thank you, but I still don't get it. I tried to apply this code                                       
    /*public ClientController()
    {
    Response=fetchData('GET');
    }
    */                                                   I get this error: Unauthorized endpoint, please check Setup->Security->Remote site settings. endpoint = https://ap4.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/api/PackageLicense

Comment: Do exactly as the error suggests - add the endpoint to the Remote Site Settings